# Android Studio не отображаются файлы в проекте

Tags: android, android-studio

В проекте есть версия для телефонов и планшетов. Для телефонов все файлы помешены в папку phone, а для планшетов в папку  tablet. Проблема в том что файлы в папке table не отображаются пока не выберешь режим отображения Project Files, тогда он их показывает но не проверяет синтаксис. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: в том, что папка не подключена

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как подключить папку.

Comment: `phone`, `tablet` -- это `productFlavors` как я понимаю?

Comment: Да это productFlavors